# Excel running total with condition

Tags: excel, sumifs

I need to create a running total of amounts in the last 12 months in Excel, but only include amounts which match criteria specified in another column.

Here is the spreadsheet:

### [image]

So far, to get the unconditional 12 month running total I have:

```
=SUMIF(D$2:D2,">="& DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2)-12,DAY(D2)),E$2:E2)
```

I want to populate column H with the same 12 month running total, but it should disregard any rows where column F is not equal to "Non-EU".

So far I tried concatenating the SUMIF with  & F2="Non-EU",E$2:E2) but this produces 0 for all rows.

Please can anyone suggest a method to acheive this?

Comment: Use SUMIFS(), pay attention to the change of order

Comment: Look into [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) function

Comment: Why are you using `MONTH(D2)-12` instead of `YEAR(D2)-1` ?

Comment: =SUMIFS(E$2:E2,D$2:D2,">="& DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2)-12,DAY(D2)),F2:F2,"<> Non-EU" )

This results in #Value! for all except first row

Comment: =SUMIFS(E$2:E2,D$2:D2,">="& DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2)-12,DAY(D2)),F$2:F2,"<> Non-EU" )

Result in same value as the original SUMIF

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
=SUMIFS(E$2:E2,D$2:D2,">="& DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2)-12,DAY(D2)),F$2:F2,"<>Non-EU" )
```

Thanks to all for suggestions.